# Heroku/Git deployment not deploying 100%

Tags: git, heroku

I am trying to deploy my application to my heroku instance, but every time I do, the script runs through the bundling of Gems, then seems to fail after deploying hooks.

Here is my deployment code:
`git push staging stage:master # stage`

Here is the console log from the deployment:

```
Denniss-MacBook-Pro:recruittalk-v1 dennismonsewicz$ git push staging stage:master
Counting objects: 29, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17/17), 1.58 KiB, done.
Total 17 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Using rake (10.0.3)
       Using aasm (3.0.16)
       Using i18n (0.6.1)
       Using multi_json (1.6.1)
       Using activesupport (3.2.12)
       Using builder (3.0.4)
       Using activemodel (3.2.12)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using journey (1.0.4)
       Using rack (1.4.5)
       Using rack-cache (1.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using hike (1.2.1)
       Using tilt (1.3.3)
       Using sprockets (2.2.2)
       Using actionpack (3.2.12)
       Using mime-types (1.21)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.12)
       Using mail (2.4.4)
       Using actionmailer (3.2.12)
       Using arbre (1.0.1)
       Using sass (3.2.6)
       Using thor (0.17.0)
       Using bourbon (3.1.1)
       Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
       Using orm_adapter (0.4.0)
       Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Using json (1.7.7)
       Using rdoc (3.12.1)
       Using railties (3.2.12)
       Using warden (1.2.1)
       Using devise (2.2.3)
       Using fastercsv (1.5.5)
       Using formtastic (2.2.1)
       Using has_scope (0.5.1)
       Using responders (0.9.3)
       Using inherited_resources (1.3.1)
       Using jquery-rails (2.2.1)
       Using kaminari (0.14.1)
       Using arel (3.0.2)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.35)
       Using activerecord (3.2.12)
       Using polyamorous (0.5.0)
       Using meta_search (1.1.3)
       Using activeresource (3.2.12)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using rails (3.2.12)
       Using activeadmin (0.5.1)
       Using acts-as-taggable-on (2.3.3)
       Using addressable (2.3.3)
       Using airbrake (3.1.8)
       Using excon (0.16.10)
       Using formatador (0.2.4)
       Using net-ssh (2.6.5)
       Using net-scp (1.0.4)
       Using nokogiri (1.5.6)
       Using ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
       Using fog (1.9.0)
       Using asset_sync (0.5.4)
       Using heroku-api (0.3.7)
       Using facter (1.6.17)
       Using timers (1.1.0)
       Using celluloid (0.12.4)
       Using connection_pool (1.0.0)
       Using redis (3.0.2)
       Using redis-namespace (1.2.1)
       Using sidekiq (2.7.4)
       Using autoscaler (0.2.0)
       Using uuidtools (2.1.3)
       Using aws-sdk (1.8.3.1)
       Using will_paginate (3.0.4)
       Using bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.9)
       Using cancan (1.6.9)
       Using multipart-post (1.1.5)
       Using faraday (0.8.5)
       Using faraday_middleware (0.9.0)
       Using hashie (1.2.0)
       Using checkdin (0.3.1)
       Using climate_control (0.0.3)
       Using cocaine (0.5.1)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
       Using execjs (1.4.0)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Using columnize (0.3.6)
       Using crummy (1.7.0)
       Using debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.9)
       Using debugger-linecache (1.1.2)
       Using debugger (1.2.0)
       Using devise-encryptable (0.1.1)
       Using faker (1.1.2)
       Using formtastic-bootstrap (2.0.0)
       Using friendly_id (4.0.9)
       Using httpauth (0.2.0)
       Using jquery-ui-rails (4.0.1)
       Using jwt (0.1.5)
       Using kgio (2.8.0)
       Using koala (1.6.0)
       Using mandrill-api (1.0.24)
       Using mandrill_mailer (0.3.2)
       Using subexec (0.2.2)
       Using mini_magick (3.5.0)
       Using negative_captcha (0.3.2)
       Using nested_form (0.3.1)
       Using newrelic_rpm (3.5.7.59)
       Using oauth (0.4.7)
       Using oauth2 (0.8.1)
       Using omniauth (1.1.3)
       Using omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
       Using omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
       Using omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
       Using omniauth-twitter (0.0.14)
       Using panda (1.6.0)
       Using paper_trail (2.7.1)
       Using paperclip (3.4.1)
       Using pg (0.14.1)
       Using rabl (0.8.0)
       Using rails3_acts_as_paranoid (0.2.5)
       Using raindrops (0.10.0)
       Using ransack (0.7.2)
       Using rest-client (1.6.7)
       Using roboto (0.1.0)
       Using rubyzip (0.9.9)
       Using ruby-ole (1.2.11.6)
       Using spreadsheet (0.8.1)
       Using roo (1.10.2)
       Using ruby-units (1.4.2)
       Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Using scoped_search (2.4.0)
       Using simple_oauth (0.2.0)
       Using sorted (0.4.3)
       Using squeel (1.0.17)
       Using stripe (1.7.11)
       Using twitter (4.5.0)
       Using uglifier (1.3.0)
       Using unicorn (4.6.1)
       Using yard (0.8.4.1)
       Using versionist (0.3.1)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> web, worker
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake

-----> Compiled slug size: 46.1MB
-----> Launching... done, v248
-----> Deploy hooks scheduled, check output in your logs
       http://staging-recruittalk.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:staging-recruittalk.git
   6a1debe..de4a9ce  stage -> master
```

Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the logs? The Deploy Hooks are for [sending notifications](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks) about the deploy, I don't think that is relevant.

Comment: @jordelver - I figured it out... It was failing during the precompile due to a syntax error

Comment: Please close the question.

Comment: @dennismonsewicz ah, glad you found it. Did you figure that out from the logs? Or somewhere else?